# Restrict panning to paths in Leaflet

Tags: navigation, leaflet, panning

I want to restrict the panning in leaflet to paths, preferrably more than one. The idea is that it is only possible to pan along roads, or a precalculated trajectory, and not freely across the map.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-options

maxBounds seems to restrict to a rectangular area only. Dynamically resetting the rectangle to keep users close to the path seems like a possibility but not a pretty one.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is indeed using the `maxBounds` option or the `setMaxBounds` method of your `L.Map` instance. If for example you want to restrict the map's bounds to a polyline, you'll need the bounds of that polyline. You don't have to calculate that yourself, you can use the `getBounds` method of the `L.Polyline` class which returns a `L.LatLngBounds` object. That object can be uses with the `setMaxBounds` method of `L.Map`:

```
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {...});

var polyline = new L.Polyline([
    [52.366667, 4.9],
    [51.507222, -0.1275]
]).addTo(map);

// Get bounds
var bounds = polyline.getBounds();

// Set view to bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);

// Restrict view to bounds
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jFw7mB?p=preview

The `getBounds` method exists on all classes extended from `L.Path` like `L.MultiPolyline`, `L.Polygon`, `L.MultiPolygon`, `L.Rectangle`, `L.Circle` and `L.CircleMarker`.

It also exists on layers `L.FeatureGroup` and `L.GeoJSON` which comes in very handy if you need to set the bounds to multiple features on your map. You contain them in a `L.FeatureGroup` and then call the `getBounds` method on the `L.FeatureGroup` instance:

```
// Empty featuregroup
var featureGroup = new L.FeatureGroup().addTo(map);

// Add some features to featuregroup
var polyline1 = new L.Polyline([
    [52.366667, 4.9],
    [51.507222, -0.1275]
]).addTo(featureGroup);

var polyline2 = new L.Polyline([
    [52.366667, 4.9],
    [48.8567, 2.3508]
]).addTo(featureGroup);

var polyline3 = new L.Polyline([
    [52.366667, 4.9],
    [52.516667, 13.383333]
]).addTo(featureGroup);

// Get bounds of featuregroup
var bounds = featureGroup.getBounds();

// Set view to bounds
map.fitBounds(bounds);

// Restrict view to bounds
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/yoax8c?p=preview

Reference:

- L.Map.setBounds: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds
- L.Map.setMaxBounds: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setmaxbounds
- L.Path.getBounds: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-getbounds
- L.FeatureGroup.getBounds: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup-getbounds

Comment: That's the first thing I found, but not the thing I was looking for. If you  zoom in a little bit on that example and then pan around, you can move the path off screen. This creates even more of a problem with paths that aren't just a straight line. What I want is that panning is restricted to diagonally along that line, keeping it in the center of the shown area of the map.